# media9 windowed not working

Tags: media9, video

I'm trying to embed a mp4 video file into a latex document. My attempt was to use the media9 package. The problem is that I want the video to play in full screen mode, which I couldn't achieve so far.
The video has a resolution of 1366x768 pixels (which is the resolution of my screen). I tried to use the "windowed" option of the media9 package, but it does not seem to have any effect at all.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
    \includemedia[width=0.4\textwidth,addresource=example-movie.mp4,windowed=1366x768,flashvars={source=example-movie.mp4}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}{VPlayer.swf}%
\end{document}
```

Note: For me the video cannot be played using Adobe Reader to view the pdf, but it works using PDF-XChange Editor.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Please strip down your example further, the issue is likely not related to USenglish language or beamer. Does the example compile for you? Where does `VPlayer.swf` come from?

Comment: Well, I need some documentclass. So why not beamer? The same problem also arises if I use the article documentclass. I have changed the MWE accordingly. VPlayer.swf is part of the media9 package. And yes, the example does compile for me...

Comment: Thanks. I can compile the document too. However the film does not play at all independant of screen resolution. Did you manage to embed and play the film using other options or another program? I mean, is it a LaTeX or a player issue?

Comment: I get a `General File Format Error` in Acrobat Preflight when reporting PDF syntax issues. Type: CosName, Formal Representation: Annot, Value: /RichMedia.

Comment: As I said, it does not work using Adobe Acrobat. Using PDF XChange Editor the video opens in a small floating window and plays. Without the windowed option it does also work.

Comment: I tried to display a sample PDF with video in Acrobat DC, Chrome, Edge, SumatraPDF. None of them displays videos. To me it looks like including videos in a PDF is not a smart thing to do. I doubt this is related to LaTeX.

Comment: Your example works for me, current AR DC on Windows, Flash still enabled. Though I had to reduce to playback window size a bit, e. g. `480x270`, to fit into the viewer window.